# Overlap 2 div borders

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this setup at the moment. I would like it so that when you hover over a box the bottom border changes to the same colour as inside the hovered div. I am starting to think this cannot be done with just css, but how would you add javascript to do this?

Any guidance would be appreciated

http://jsfiddle.net/hCK3D/7/

Comment: Are you looking for something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/jklm313/hCK3D/10/

Comment: How that is behaving is exactly what I require. Except the white dividing vertical borders disrupt the horizontal borders too which I do not want to happen.

Comment: I don't really understand what you meant by that. Could you perhaps make a quick image in paint/photoshop that better illustrates how you want the hover behavior?

Comment: Please see my answer for a solution with what was missing from jklm's solution

Comment: See my answer with no disrupted borders.. http://jsfiddle.net/hCK3D/17/

Comment: hmm, identical to http://jsfiddle.net/hCK3D/15/ @JamesCazzetta

Comment: @JDandChips That was my first attempt to this solution. You can see that I clicked on the Update button instead of first running it first, that's all. :)

Comment: No sorry, jsfiddle.net/hCK3D/16 was my first attempt to this solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Overlap div container border with item border on hover

**Unlike** the other answers posted, this solution will allow you to keep the border line on the bottom: http://jsfiddle.net/hCK3D/15/ **and** your white vertical lines will continue to appear correctly.

The idea is that the border from the bottom is now set in the item, and when the item is hovered the bottom border changes colour to match the hover colour. **Also** the container border is set for the purpose of the white vertical lines, but on hover the item hover border bottom appears in front of the container border.

[See the JSFiddle for source](http://jsfiddle.net/hCK3D/15/)

Comment: Thank you your answer is very helpful. I shall accept it as you have helped me to achieve what I wanted. There is only one issue. Which is it is not pixel perfect. I am thinking I may not be able to fix this, but when you have over a div the right border at the very bottom is actually the light grey whereas I would like to have it continue the border to the bottom. It is 1 single pixel

Comment: I fixed it by removing the border from the hover in the css

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just remove the bottom-border on hover and instead make the element 1px bigger in height? (You do not need to add any JavaScript codes)

Like this:
http://jsfiddle.net/hCK3D/17/

**UPDATE**: Now also the border is not disrupted..

**UPDATED CSS**:

```
.item-container {
    float:left;
    margin-top:20px;
    border-bottom: 1px #BCC0C3 solid;
    height:100px;
}
.item {
    float:left;
    background: #ccc;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-left: 1px #fff solid;
    border-top: 1px #BCC0C3 solid;
    border-bottom: 1px #BCC0C3 solid;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.item:first-child {
    border-left: 1px #BCC0C3 solid;
}
.item:last-child {
    border-right: 1px #BCC0C3 solid;
}
.item:hover {
    background:#ECEFF4;
    border-left:1px #BDC0C5 solid;
    border-right:1px #BDC0C5 solid;
    border-bottom: 0;
    height:101px;
}
.item:hover + .item {
    border-left-width: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

do you mean like this?

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hCK3D/11/)

```
.body{background:#ECEFF4;}
.item-container {
    float:left;
    border-top: 1px solid #BCC0C3;
    margin-top:20px;
}
.item {
    float:left;
    background: #ccc;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-left: 1px solid #fff ;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #BCC0C3;
}

.item:first-child {border-left: 1px solid #BCC0C3;}
.item:last-child {border-right: 1px solid #BCC0C3;}

.item:hover {
    background:#ECEFF4;
    border-left:1px solid #BDC0C5;
    border-right:1px solid #BDC0C5;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ECEFF4;
}

.item:hover + .item {border-left-width: 0;}
```